# Can't open "Datastore Admin"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project including a problem.
After I enabled Datastore Admin, I clicked "Open Datastore Admin" button.
However, I faced an error of "500 Internal Server Error".
An error message is as follows.

> The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

In other project, I can open Datastore Admin normally.
I deployed the program of correct project to GAE by eclipse, but same error has occurred.
I cannot find a solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report for this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10150&q=%22datastore%20admin%22&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

"This looks to be a problem because you are using non-default authentication scheme.

Are you using user service/Google Accounts API for authentication of users inside your application? If not, consider changing your authentication method.

If you are, then you'll need to setup a custom domain and access the datastore admin via:
https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-
so that the correct authentication cookies can be used."

I have the same issue, I'm using simpleauth for authentication and I suspect that is the problem... but I haven't solved it yet, changing my authentication scheme is not an option.